# Password security standards in web development

Tags: php, security

I am just wondering, Is it standard to allow an administrator or more privileged user that has higher access than a public user to be able to change that public users password?

Comment: Dont know about standards but i think its not a good idea, as password change permission should be limited to owner of the password only..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If the *administrator* is going to change password of a *public user*, it can never be standard, but also cannot be acceptable for any *public user*.

---

**Long answer:**

First of all, lets take a look at standard password protected systems which have multilevel users ranging from *super user/administrator* to the users you are calling *public users* or otherwise may be known as *registered users/members*.

A password protected system may be an official website of an organization or institute or company or even may be only a website blog.

Normally the *super users/administrators* may be the owners or at least the organizers of the system.

*Public users* normally may also be known as *registered users/members* may be customers or simply public beneficiaries of that password protected system.

*Super user/administrator* though itself is a user level, still it is supposed to manage all the users including *registered users*.

Now lets see, is there any situation which may lead *super user/administrator* to change password of *public user(s)*? First we have to imagine some scenarios while working with some password protected system:

**Scenario 1:** Some *public user* may have forgotten their password.

In this scenario a *public user* may forgot his/her password. Now to regain access to his/her website account, he/she needs either to remember his/her forgotten password or change his/her forgotten password with some new. If he/she is unable to remember his/her current password, then there is only the possibility to change password. Now still the *public user* should have access to change his/her password. But it is also possible that system itself changes the password and sends back to the user through e-mail, still it is not done manually by any *administrator*.

**Scenario 2:** Some *public user* may have violated some rules, regulation or TOS presented by the website publisher and *administrator* wants to block him/her.

In this scenario some *public user* have done some violation of such level that he/she is not bearable as *registered member* then *administrator* has legal right to block that *public user*. Still *administrator* is not going to touch password of that user.

**Conclusion:**

*Administrator* shouldn't, or rather can't, change password of some *public user* though there may be possibility of such a system that may exist only on LAN (Local Area Network) or some other sort of small system, where *administrator* if changes the password of some *registered user*, then only and only with his/her consent.

Comment: Please, use less bold, it seems like you are shouting.

Comment: @JohnPalmer thanks for the advice, shall take care of that in future. But just for sake of information, is this only for this site or using bold words inside text anywhere means shouting. (I mean like if we use it in our official letters or other marketing materials.)

Comment: I think using bold like you had used it before reads like shouting.  The current version is quite good